# Build native library and JAR at the same time

Tags: android, jar, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am trying to build a JAR file that I can import and use it for other android projects.
I created Android project that contains java code (src/main.java) and it calls bunch of native code I wrote (Using System.loadLibrary(...))
Under jni folder, I have bunch of C/C++ codes, for instance jni/sample/sample.cpp.
My question is that when I export this project to JAR, can I build native library at the same time?
In other words, do I need to have pre-built .so file before exporting to JAR file?
My goal is when I export or something like that, it will do:
Build C/C++ code and create .so files --> Build .java ---> JAR
at once.

Comment: What IDE are you using? And are you opposed to more complicated build systems?

Comment: @Dave It is eclipse and your answer definitely helped me a lot! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Eclipse, you can create a "Launch Group" in your debug/run configurations. That way you can include your Java build and an Android Native Application build in one configuration.

If you are looking to move to a more sophisticated build system, you should look into Maven. It is considerably more complex than the plain old debug/run configurations, but it is much more powerful. It includes an apklib packaging to build libraries for Android. There are a few quirks with using the NDK in an apklib, but reasonable project design can avoid most problems.